# Which development board is good to learn ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I wanted to learn ARM assembly and Bare metal programming and planning to buy some development board.

I have limited budget and can spend up to $75(4500 rupees).From Google I can see that Raspberry Pi board comes in my budget.

So is it okay to buy Raspberry Pi board and start to learn ARM assembly programming?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is certainly a nice platform to play with (albeit one with somewhat limited need for low-level assembly code) but beware that the peripheral equipment needed may blow your budget. A "free" option to get you started would be to first play with a simulator, there are any number out there. Why not write a GBA game for instance?

Comment: @doynax ,I am looking at this link https://www.crazypi.com/raspberry-pi-complete-kit. would it contain all the peripheral to start with?

Comment: That should be about it, yes. Aside from a monitor and keyboard of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some stuff on github which I wont link here, you can also go to the bare metal forum on the raspberry pi website and get a fair amount of good info.

The raspberry pi is a very good platform for learning bare metal...other than the documentation...The chip is very easy to program, easier than a number of microcontrollers and other items in that price range.  In order to start with bare metal on a raspberry pi you will need a raspberry pi, the A model will work and save you $10 if you want.  You will need to buy an sd card, and you will want/need to buy a usb to serial adapter, some flavor of ftdi part.  Sparkfun has a number of these.  Search for ftdi basic breakout.  You will also need two wires one for tx on the uart one for rx on the uart, plus usb cables micro-b for the raspberry pi and mini-b for most of the ftdi boards but not all.  Sparkfun also carries jumper wires, you need to plan ahead and get the right male/female, or female/female (m/f, f/f) you wont need male/male since the raspberry pi side is male.  or if you get one of the breakouts that just has a hole you might stick the wire in and twist it or something.  Push comes to shove trash bag and bread back twist ties have a little wire in them and you could probably use one of those if on a really tight budget, just dont short them to each other or anything else.

there are a number of tutorials including mine on how to get started with bare metal programming on the raspberry pi.  I will let you google those.  You can certainly get started within your budget using a raspberry pi (sparkfun carries raspberry pi boards as well, you can get everything you need there and only pay for shipping once).

The beaglebone black only needs a usb cable and sd card, I dont remember if the sd card comes with it.  Or the usb cable.  more I/O, the arm address space is more complicated and the ti manuals are harder to read and find stuff.  broadcom (raspberry pi) is know for none to little and poor docs, where ti has excessively complete docs just not as nice as others to wade through.  A bit of a tradeoff.  A good alternative to a raspberry pi within your price range.

The above are linux capable systems which you should just let the bootloader scheme bring up the ddr (memory), you dont want to go there even with experience.  And they are full blown arm processors, arm and thumb instruction set.

Another path you can take is the microcontrollers, there is for example the stm32f0 discovery which is under $10 before shipping.  A good platform for learning as well and you definitely bare metal and you can learn assembly, but only thumb assembly.  Whether you start with arm or thumb is not something I feel strongly about, I used to lean the other way but am starting to lean toward thumb first then arm...the st website (st.com) will have links to the boards, mouser and digikey and the usual players will carry them.  I recommend getting a couple in case you blow one up and also the shipping from those places is painful so if you are going to spend as much as the board on shipping might as well get more than one and offset that shipping cost.  Actually if/when you want to do serial with the stm32f0 discovery you will want/need one of those usb to serial ftdi things, 3.3 volt.  assume 3.3v unless you are going with something pretty old or an arduino/avr (although some of those have 3.3 volt versions

They renamed it but ti has a launchpad for the formerly stellar is board (tiva or something now) that is also an cortex-m based processor (thumb only).  the launchpads are free shipping and are also in the sub 20 or sub 10 dollar range and can also be used for this learning of bare metal and assembly.  Problem there is they only do production runs every so often and you might have to wait months to get your board.  They also have a hercules set of boards for $20 which are full blown arm processors, but so far as I know are not supported by third party tools, basically you need to use code composer studio which works fine and you can do assembly and all that, but I prefer to take another approach.  I bricked one of my boards already messing with the pll without leaving myself a backdoor (I forget and do this every so often, some chips jtags are such that you can get away with not doing it and some are not, this is one that if your firmware hangs the arm you cannot recover with jtag, the cortex-m0 version of the mbed board is also like this the cortex-m3 from nxp (original mbed) is not like this).

There are a number of sub $20 microcontrollers that you may or may not want to buy an ftdi board for serial eventually that you can also use, and some more pricy ones like the mbed and the maple mini and such.

bottom line, get a simulator first, then jump into a sub $50 board, there are tons of them.  Do your research first though, make sure you can do what you want with it without having to buy more tools, serial, jtag, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[LPC810](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m0_m0/LPC810M021FN8.html), [costs $1.37](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m0_m0/LPC810M021FN8.html).

[image]

8 legs (DIP8), 32-bit ARM Cortex-M0+ microcontroller; 4 kB flash and 1 kB SRAM.

Just imagine the possibilities... :)

Comment: As far as I know the Cortex-M0+ (like most Cortex cores) only supports Thumb(-2) instructions (an alternate instruction set for ARM which is not similar to the original ARM instruction set at all), but not the original ARM instructions. Not a good idea to use this if you want to learn ARM assembler!

Comment: @MartinRosenau ARM nowadays promotes UAL (Unified assembly language) which can end up as Thumb-2 or ARM instructions most of the time. So I don't think it is a big issue as much as you point. Normally these kinds of question are frowned upon on SO but I couldn't hold myself from mentioning a Cortex-M0+ in a DIP8 package. I think it is pretty cool :)

Comment: This is correct. However Thumb-2 does not support all instructions ARM supports. Maybe Amit Singh Tomar also wants to write machine code instructions to RAM and execute them from there. Many people learning assembler do such things for learning purposes. In this case Thumb-2 and ARM can also not be considered equal. So we have to ask Amit Singh Tomar: "Why ARM assembler and not any other assembler?" If the answer is: "Just because it is simple" (or similar) Cortex processors can be used, of course.

Comment: the cortex-m0 is an armv6m which only has about 30 or so thumb2 extensions, the cortex m3 and m4 have about 140 or so thumb2 extensions.  thumb (without extensions) is not a bad place to start learning arm assembly and arm architecture.  thumb (with extensions) does have a one to one (thumb to arm only) relationship with arm instructions.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: While it is true that some ARM instructions (hello RSC) do not have Thumb-2 equivalents, this is purely semantically relevant - Thumb-2 supports all functionality available to the ARM instruction set. However, like dwelch says, Cortex-M0+ does not in fact support Thumb-2, only a minor superset of Thumb. So to me it makes for a better C-programming target than an asm one.

Comment: also note that thumb (without extensions) is the only universal arm instruction set, support from armv4t to the present, cortex-m and non-m.  Not a bad place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go in here on pure principle and argue against the Raspberry PI. While a complete game-changer in how it proved that there is a huge market for low-cost, high-performance development boards, and its huge community gives it extra clout in ease-of-getting-stuff-working if you are using it for a specific project, it is to me one of the worst learning-platforms I can think of.

Which is the right one all comes down to what aspect of assembly programming you are interested.

- If you want something to practise asm programming for learning about the latest ARM processors, the Raspberry PI is an ancient thing which will leave you unable to access any of the features introduced in ARMv7 - including the NEON SIMD extensions.
- If you want to learn low-level system programming, then the design of the SoC on the Raspberry PI is simply going to confuse things for you. The CPU is not the master of that piece of silicon - you need the Videocore GPU to load the software for you.
- If you want to run general-purpose Linux on the board, then the Raspberry PI forces you to choose between relying on specific RasPi "remix" variants, or not using the hardware floating-point unit. All of the common Linux distribtions have either/or both of an ARMv5 port (without hardware floating-point support) and an ARMv7 port (which will not run on the Raspberry Pi.

For all of the above situations, I would recommend the BeagleBoard Black over the RPI. While slightly more expensive, it is still well within your budget, is a modern ARMv7 architecture processor and has 1GB of RAM.

If what you want is to learn real-time or microcontroller programming, then doing that on anything with an MMU is just going to complicate things. For that I would recommend something different - like one of the [mbed](http://mbed.org/) platforms.

If you are looking to learn about microcontrollers, then the exception handling model is completely different between the ARM M-profile and the higher-level A- and R- profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi is a ARM-based standalone computer which is designed to run operating system such as (but not limited to) Linux.  As such, it would be possible to write code in ARM assembly language that would interact with such operating systems, but most aspects of the way things like interrupts are configured will be dictated by the OS rather than your code.  By contrast, many evaluation boards are designed to make it easy to load in your code all by itself, giving it complete control over everything in the system.  Something like a "hello world" program may be more difficult to set up, but you'd be able to have much more precise control over everything that's happening than would be possible using a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I think bare metal programming means there would be no underlying OS.You will load your program to flash(in Raspberry Pi case it would be SD cards) and Do little things which OS is doing for you.In that manner I wanted to learn different concept of OS like interrupt Handling for ARM architecture.

Comment: Beware that to effectively do this type of low-level systems programming on the Pi you will pretty much need JTAG debugger, else you're in for a lot of pain

Comment: @doynax: Some boards include some form of a USB-to-JTAG interface; in some cases it may be limited to programming/debugging only the exact chip which is installed on the eval board.  I don't have any particular product recommendations, though I've used boards from ST Micro, Energy Micro, and Freescale; the latter were the cheapest but I preferred the boards I used from the first two vendors; I don't know how current offerings compare with what I used, however.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: The manufacturer of the ARM chip used in the Raspberry Pi has not, so far as I know, made public all the information necessary for bare-metal programming on that chip.

Comment: @supercat would you like to suggest any board which comes with lots of documentation on bare-metal programming and budget under 80$.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi really shines as an embedded linux platform; not as a ARM dev board. As has been noted many times, once you buy the peropherals (even running headless you'll need a power supply, case, JTAG interface, hub if you need external storage - you have cables, though, right?), it will cost around $75. You better spec out all the peripherals you need as your budget is tight. I think a better bet for straight ARM assembly is to go the MCU route - TI Stellaris ($10 or so). If you're willing to forego ARM architecture, but still want to cut your teeth on a RISC-like MCU board, try the MSP430 for an amazing $4.97. It isn't ARM, so it may not suit you.

Answer (score 1):

There are evaluation boards with an Atmel SAM7 (that has an ARM7TDMI core) from Olimex.

The SAM7 series chips have a built-in boot loader that allows programming the chips via USB.

Two different memory sizes are available for 25 and 30 Euro (2100 or 2550 Rupi).

Unfortunately they deliver in Europe and not in India but maybe similar boards are available in India, too.

--- Edit ---

The advantage of a Raspberry Pi (compare to these boards) would be the Linux on the board: debugging and data exchange to the PC is very easy.

The Raspberry Pi is a bit more expensive but use is much easier!